# I am trying to install Python 2.7 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. (AMD Athlon II X4 635 2.90 GHz) 4 GB RAM

Tags: python

I installed the 2.5.6 version from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/ (the .tgz). It seems to have installed correctly, but I am having problems when I go to use it. I open up the command-line version, and it looks OK, but if I type any commands and try to execute them it gives me errors.

This is my first venture into Python, and I could be doing this completely wrong. I am also unable to change directories using the command line. I have a sample program in a directory: ex1.py. I see the following in my command prompt:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64-bit (AMD64)] on Windows 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I entered the following:

```
>>> python ex1.py
```

The following message returned:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  python ex1.py
          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Now it could be a syntax error, but I do not see anything; it is a simple "Hello world" program. I am not comfortable with the install and fear I may have screwed things up.

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to type `python ex1.py` outside the Python shell, on the command prompt, not inside the Python shell.

Comment: I did this and I am getting a syntax error. My entire program is:

Print "test!"

I am not sure if i have downloaded a different version but the sample that I am learning from has this as the syntax. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Silspar24 - it's `print "test!"` not `Print "test!"`

Comment: Use brackets, print("test")

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be wrong, and one that is definitely wrong.

#### Things that are definitely wrong

- When executing a file, type `python ex1.py` from the command prompt, *not* inside the Python interpreter.

#### Things that could be wrong

- If you have Python 3.x installed, when printing "Hello World!" make sure you use brackets in `print`, ex:

  Right:

  `print('Hello World!')`

  Wrong:

  `print 'Hello World!'`

Also, if you have Python 2.7 or earlier installed, this is still a good habit to get into when programming, and will make the eventual transition to 3.x much smoother.

- You said in your example that you typed `Print "Hello World"` - in this example the `print` function/statement should *not* be capitalized.